# Get tree structure of folders

Tags: sql-server

I have the following folders in the table 'Folders' in my database:

- Folder1
- Folder2
- Folder3
- Folder4

The path of the folders - Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Folder4

When i click on Folder3,i have to get the path as - Folder1\Folder2\Folder3.For this i am passing the folderID of Folder3.

How can i get this result ?

### table structure

### FolderiD FolderName ParentID

1          Folder1    0

2          Folder2    1

3          Folder3    2

4          Folder4    3

Comment: What does this have to do with SQL Server?

Comment: what does sql server and folders have to do with each other ?

Comment: What is the structure of the table `folders`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the answer I gave when this question was repeated here: [How to query hierarchical information with SQL-Server 2000?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3863401/how-to-query-hierarchical-information-with-sql-server-2000/3864252#3864252)

```
/* Set up test data */
create table Folders (
    FolderID int,
    FolderName varchar(10),
    ParentID int
)

insert into Folders
    (FolderID, FolderName, ParentID)
    select 1,'Folder1',0 union all
    select 2,'Folder2',1 union all
    select 3,'Folder3',2 union all
    select 4,'Folder4',3        
go

/* Create function */
create function dbo.CreateFolderPath (@FolderID int)
returns varchar(1000)
as
begin
    declare @ParentID int
    declare @FolderPath varchar(1000)
    set @FolderPath = ''

    select @ParentID = ParentID
        from Folders
        where FolderID = @FolderID

    while @ParentID<>0 begin
        select @FolderPath = FolderName + '\' + @FolderPath, @ParentID = ParentID
            from Folders
            where FolderID = @ParentID
    end /* while */

    return @FolderPath
end /* function */
go

/* Demo the function */
select dbo.CreateFolderPath(4)

/* Clean up after demo */
drop function dbo.CreateFolderPath
drop table Folders
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive CTE for this.

```
/*Test Data*/
SELECT *
INTO #Folders FROM 
(SELECT 1 AS FolderId, 0 AS ParentId, 'Folder1' AS FolderName UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS FolderId, 1 AS ParentId, 'Folder2' AS FolderName UNION ALL
SELECT 3 AS FolderId, 2 AS ParentId, 'Folder3' AS FolderName UNION ALL
SELECT 4 AS FolderId, 3 AS ParentId, 'Folder4' AS FolderName ) F


/*Query*/    
;WITH fl AS
     ( SELECT 1 AS Level,
             FolderId   ,
             ParentId   ,
             FolderName ,
             CAST(FolderName AS nvarchar(MAX)) AS F
     FROM    #Folders
     WHERE   FolderId = 3

     UNION ALL

     SELECT Level +1    ,
            f.FolderId  ,
            f.ParentId  ,
            f.FolderName,
            CAST(f.FolderName + '/' + fl.F AS nvarchar(MAX))
     FROM   fl
            JOIN #Folders f
            ON     fl.ParentId = f.FolderId
     )
SELECT   top (1) F
FROM     fl
ORDER BY Level DESC

drop table #Folders
```

Comment: @Adu - Nope. You would need to use a `WHILE` loop for that or recursively call a table valued function.